# MS Access, filter by or search array of values

Tags: arrays, list, ms-access, filter

I want to rapidly search an Access database for a list of part serial numbers. I want to believe there is a quicker way than to "filter by → contains → (paste single number for list of parts)" one at a time. Can one of the built-in filters help me? Is there another way? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the filter box, select *Equal to:* and then:

```
NO1 or NO3 or NO7
```

where the NOx are your serial numbers.

Comment: Sorry, but that is just as tedious when I have hundreds or records to look up.

Comment: Have in mind, please, that we have only the information you publish here. Write the S/Ns to a table, create a select query having this table and the main table with an inner join on the S/N fields.